# Google Chrome Extension: A way to make a non-visible tab behave as if it were visible?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, twitter

I am writing a Chrome extension that scrapes data from Twitter, specifically from [twitter.com/following](http://twitter.com/following), using a content script. I want to run this in a tab/window that is not active or visible to the user, so as to not be disruptive.

Now, Twitter loads much of its content using scripts, so I am using `MutationObserver` and `window.scrollBy` to force the content to load. This works perfectly fine when the tab is visible. However, when the tab is not visible (inacive tab or window that is minimized/offscreen), it does not work. Firstly, the `setInterval` timers get throttled to once a second. I did some research and I think I can fix this using `requestAnimationFrame`, but have not tested yet. The more pressing problem is that the content that I am looking for, ie. the list of followed accounts, no longer gets loaded by Twitter's scripts.

I have tried to spoof the tab as always visible using this code snippet, but it did not fix the issue.

```
Object.defineProperty(document, "visibilityState", {
    get() {
        return "visible";
    }
});

document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```

Is there any way to give non-visible tabs the functionality of visible tabs, if temporarily?

PS: I know that Twitter has an API, but I would prefer to not have to deal with hosting an application if I can avoid it.

Comment: This code should be placed in [page context](/a/9517879).

Comment: I made a extension a long time ago https://github.com/zoutepopcorn/scroll. I didn't face the problem then. Maybe add some dummy audio or video to keep the page active?

Comment: Or maybe using a chrome.runtime.sendmessage() with the setInterval() in the background.js. activating the twitter tab to execute a function ?

Comment: Did you ever get this working?